# postgres query (more than function)

Tags: postgresql

Let's assume that I have 2 tables: Human, Car.
Table Car has some columns and one of them is Human_id. For example, like this:

```
Human_id Type
1        BMW
5        Mercedes
1        Audi
2        Peugeot
3        BMW
2        JEEP
```

How can I select all humans who have more than one car? I mean I need to control if Human_id is used more than once in the Human_id column. But how I can do that?

```
SELECT human.name
FROM Human, Car
WHERE .... <- what goes here??
```

Comment: having = where clause on aggregate (must have group by)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT human.name, car.human_id, count(*) as total
FROM Human, Car
group by human.name, car.human_id
having count(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try grouping your `Car` records by `Human_id`, and take a look at the `HAVING` clause.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a FK between *Human* and *Car* tables, it's best to use a **Join** instead of a Cartesian product:

```
create table Human (
  idHuman integer primary key,
  name varchar(15),
   ...
);
insert into Human (idHuman, name) values
  (1,'A'), (2,'B'), (3,'C'), (4,'D'), (5,'E');

create table Car (
  Human_id integer REFERENCES Human ON DELETE CASCADE,
  Type varchar(15),
  ...
);
insert into Car (Human_id, Type) values 
  (1,'BMW'), (5,'Mercedes'), (1,'Audi')
 ,(2,'Peugeot'), (3,'BMW'), (2,'JEEP');
```

And the query:

```
select hu.name
from Human hu
join Car ca on (ca.Human_id = hu.idHuman)
group by hu.name
having count(*) > 1
```

I hope that I help you

Answer (score -1):

```
 select human.name
 from human
 where human.id in
      select human.id
      from car
      where count(car) > 1
      group by human.id
```

Comment: I have an error -> aggregates not allowed in WHERE clause. Ant suggestions?

Comment: replace the subqurey by `(SELECT id from car GROUP BY  id having COUNT(*) > 1)`

Comment: Indeed sorry. Haven't touched sql in a while.